# if else not working properly in functions in python program in creating leap year program

Tags: python, function, if-statement, leap-year

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        print("year is a leap year")
    elif year % 400 == 0:
        print("year is a leap year")
    elif year % 100 == 0:
        print("not a leap year")
    else:
        print("Not a leap year")

is_leap(2019)
```

1. here i have entered the year 2019 which is not leap year but my program is not giving me out put of that if you enter a non leap year it want give out put as not a leap year.
2. if there is any type of mistake in my program regarding any thing please tell me.
3. this are considerations in bellow points using which i created the program -->
4. The year must be evenly divisible by 4;
5. If the year can also be evenly divided by 100, it is not a leap year;
   unless...
6. The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

Comment: You probably just forgot to `print` in the `else`: `print("Not a leap year")`

Comment: Your else branch just produces a string and throws it away, add `print` just before the first opening bracket to call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe try like this?

```
year = int(input("Input year: "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    print("Year is leap.")
    if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0:
        print("Year is common.")

else:
    print("Year is common.")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have errors in your code, in order to check wheter or not a year is a leap year you should follow:

1. If a year is evenly divisible by 4 means having no remainder then go to next step. If it is not divisible by 4. It is not a leap year. For example: 1997 is not a leap year.
2. If a year is divisible by 4, but not by 100. For example: 2012, it is a leap year. If a year is divisible by both 4 and 100, go to next step.
3. If a year is divisible by 100, but not by 400. For example: 1900, then it is not a leap year. If a year is divisible by both, then it is a leap year. So 2000 is a leap year.

So you need to use nested `if-else` statements. Review the following simple code and try to deduce where exactly you did wrong:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if (year % 4) == 0:
       if (year % 100) == 0:
           if (year % 400) == 0:
               print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
           else:
               print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
       else:
           print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
    else:
       print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
    return

is_leap(2019)
```

**And as @Alexander Kononenko said, you were missing a `print` in your `else`.**

Comment: and for teaching me something i did not knew about stack overflow

Comment: @NimeshJoshi You removed the accept from my answer to an answer that is a simplification of the if cases. What is the rational behind it? And the code isnt correct, try inputing 1900.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to write `print` in the `else` section. Should be:

```
print("Not a leap year")
```

Comment: No chance for "2019" to get into `elif`:
2019 % 4 = 3;
2019 % 400 = 19;
2019 % 100 = 19